# Run time error -2147024809 (80070057) - Pivot Table field name is not valid

Tags: vba, excel

Got another Excel VBA Macro button issue.

I am trying to make a button to refresh all pivots on a worksheet (there are four). I have been to StackOverflow before and received a solution that worked well. I took the code I was provided before and updated it for the new workbook but it fails below with the function .ChangePivotCache PvtCache:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim PvtTbl                  As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache                As PivotCache
Dim PvtDataRng              As Range

Set PvtDataRng = Worksheets("OTR_Promo_List_ADV_2017").Range("B2:AU500")

Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, PvtDataRng)

Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Desired_Distribution").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

For Each PvtTbl In Worksheets("Desired_Distribution").PivotTables

    Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, PvtDataRng)

    With PvtTbl
        .ChangePivotCache PvtCache
        .RefreshTable
    End With

    Set PvtCache = Nothing

Next PvtTbl

End Sub
```

The only differences are that the workbook changed and now I want to refresh 4 pivots instead of 2 - could that be the issue?

Below a screenshot so you can see the worksheets. "OTR_Promo_List_ADV-2017" is the database. The Pivot tables have the default naming, I did not change the names (i.e. PivotTable1, PivotTable2...)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I remember this, but my code was a little different. First, you don't need the 2 lines of `Set PvtCache` and `Set PvtTbl` before the `For Each PvtTbl...` loop. Second, if your `Range` is not dynamic (Range("B2:AU500" is static), why do you need to run this code ?

Comment: I dont know, I literally just copied and pasted whatever I was provided here...

Answer (score 0):

The code you use to refresh all pivot tables on the one sheet seems overly complex. I don't quite understand why you would want to use `.ChangePivotCache` at all. It changes the data source of the specified pivot table. If you just want to refresh a pivot table, that is completely unwarranted.

You can use Excel Table objects as the data source for your pivot tables, then a simple refresh will suffice. Or, if you don't want to use Tables (though you may really want to look into that, for obvious reasons), you can use dynamic range names to define the pivot source. With both techniques, you only need to refresh the pivot table and don't have to manipulate the pivot cache with VBA.

With Tables or dynamic range names as the source of pivot tables, you can refresh all pivot tables on a sheet by cycling through them and refresh them with codes along these lines:

```
Sub RefreshPivotsOnSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set ws = Worksheets("MySheet")
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
End Sub
```

Edit: How to set Excel Tables as the data source for a pivot: Turn the source data into a table with Ctrl + T or Insert > Table. Then edit the Pivot Table data source and point it to the Excel table you just created.

Comment: I tried using the code provided here but it fails on the section "pt.Refreshtable" with runtime error 1004 "PivotTable field name is not valid". I may be missing something because I am not sure how to set Excel Table objects as the data source...

Comment: I added instructions about Tables for pivot sources. That code runs fine in my scenarios. What are your pivot table field names? The error says that one is not valid, so you may want to check field names for naming issues.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to close this topic. I found somewhere else a simple macro that says only:

```
Sub REFRESH()
'
' REFRESH Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

seemed to do the trick.

Thank you for all your inputs!

Comment: Dude... someone gave me that other macro from this very website. I am a complete VBA newb.

Comment: I am not complaining... just saying that spazzing on someone who is total VBA n00b that was asking for help is a bit.. unhelpful. and the code that I copied was directly in relation to a similar question I asked on here before.